# Regex match in Typescript with 2 decimal in typescript

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to have regex expressions which gets called on each press of keystroke should allow values up to 2 decimals. Most of the solutions allow it, but it didn't allow below
1.  i.e. "1." as soon as user presses. existing solutions are becoming invalid.
"1.", ".", ".12" should also be valid expressions.

The one I'm using is below

```
/^\s*-?(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$/
```

Comment: Can you list out some sample inputs which both do, and do not, match what you want?

Comment: The expression /^\s*-?(\d+(.\d{1,2})?|.\d{1,2})\s*$/   correctly validates digits like  12.3--> true , 12.35--> true, 0.35--> true but being human when I type 12.  Please note after . (dot) is typed expression becomes invalid. E..g. 12.  .I'm looking for solution which will also return true in case simply "." is pressed or "12." is entered.. Thanks

Comment: That's not data, it's the (attempted) answer.  Your comment does not help at all.

Comment: added correct comment. Please let me know if it is still not clear

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
/^\s*-?(\d*(\.?\d{0,2})?)\s*$/
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Seems it allows alpha characters as well. We just need digits and letter "."

Comment: Forgot to escape the period. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this pattern:

```
^-?\d*(?:\.|\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Some matching inputs:

```
1.
.
.12
-123
123.45
-1
0.12
```

Some non mathching inputs:

```
123.456
0.123
```

### Demo

Comment: What about `-1` or `+2` as inputs? OK, not sure about the latter but it's *usually* a valid number. OP seems to have an optional `-`, though. EDIT: now that I think about it, however, I'm not sure if `-.12` would be a valid input. Never actually thought about that before.

Comment: Super perfect!!.. Thanks a lot